# parsing a string using strtok - twice in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to parse a given string using strtok - but using it twice.
String to parse: "x=2;y=30".
Desired output:
An array of strings containing [x,y] and an array of string containing [2,30].
Meaning, I want to first use ";" as a delimiter, then using "=" as a delimiter.
How can I do that - in cpp?

Comment: Hello. Show us your code to see what is your blocking point

Comment: Do you have to use `strtok`? [boost::string::split](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.stringalgorithms#ex.stringalgorithms_11) or [std::regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) might be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, I wouldn't use [`std::strtok()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok). [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) provides nice `find` methods in multiple flavors, e.g. [`std::string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of).

As I couldn't resist to fiddle with the ancient `strtok()`, a little demo for all that:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  char input[] = "x=2;y=30";
  std::vector<char*> leftHandSides, rightHandSides;
  for (char *in = input;;) {
    char *lhs = strtok(in, "=");
    in = nullptr;
    if (!lhs) break;
    char *rhs = strtok(in, ";");
    if (!rhs) break;
    leftHandSides.push_back(lhs);
    rightHandSides.push_back(rhs);
  }
  for (size_t i = 0, n = rightHandSides.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    std::cout << leftHandSides[i] << '=' << rightHandSides[i] << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
x=2
y=30
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4418a9f741538c37)

**Notes:**

1. `strtok()` has to be called with a pointer to buffer (to tokenize) for the first time, and with a 0-pointer for further results (of same buffer). Hence, the `char *in = input;` which is overridden after `char *lhs = strtok(in, "=");` with `in = nullptr;`. It is important that this is done in the first iteration. That it happens in all other iterations as well is tolerated as it doesn't cause harm. (I could've checked with an additional `if` but hadn't won anything with this.)
2. `strtok()` modifies the input string. Hence, I used `char input[] = "x=2;y=30";` intentional.
   (With `const char *input = "x=2;y=30";`, I would've made code with [U.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior/4105123#4105123))

---

Finally, a variant using [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline()`](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `std::strtok()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::string input = "x=2;y=30";
  std::vector<std::string> leftHandSides, rightHandSides;
  for (std::istringstream in(input);;) {
    std::string lhs, rhs;
    if (!std::getline(in, lhs, '=')
      || !std::getline(in, rhs, ';')) break;
    leftHandSides.push_back(lhs);
    rightHandSides.push_back(rhs);
  }
  for (size_t i = 0, n = rightHandSides.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    std::cout << leftHandSides[i] << '=' << rightHandSides[i] << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
x=2
y=30
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fdfd52ad07d5f9b)

Comment: The second variant works very well, about strtok(), you were right. Thanks!

Comment: @SarahDe-Paz My first reflex was to use an outer loop to separate assignments and an inner part to separate LHS from RHS. But then I realized that the separators can be changed for every call of `strtok()` (even for the same input buffer). ;-)